# Jquery change class CSS on click event

Tags: jquery, css, class, onclick

Have got code similar to this to work, just cant get it to work with this instance.

Using jquery to change the CSS of the div above the link to hide the subnav (`currently stays open because link href="#"`).

All links have class of "team" and once any of them are clicked, should change subnav to display="none"

Code is:

```
$('a.team').click(function() {
    $('.subnav', this).css('display','none'); 
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a9AYE/

Comment: Can you show the `HTML`.. Also better to use a class instead of setting inline stylle

Comment: A jsFiddle would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed be using `closest` (As `subnav` is the ancestor of `.team` elements)

```
$(this).closest('subnav').css('display', 'none');
```

It is a better idea to use a `class` to change the style instead of defining them `inline`

```
.hide{
    display: none;
}
```

Just add a class to apply the specific class. Lot more cleaner and less messy.

Also prevent the default action of the link being followed.

```
$('a.team').click(function (e) {      
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.subnav').addClass('hide')
});
// This is to remove the hide class
// which has more specificity
$('.nav > li').mouseover(function (e) {   
    $('.subnav').removeClass('hide')
});
```

You will encounter `specificity` issues in this example.

When you set `display:none` inline you can only override it by specifying inline again.

Use classes instead. And you see the same issue again. But writing a more specific class should solve the issue.. And your CSS should look like below for it to work.

**CSS**

```
.nav > li .subnav {
    display:none;
}
.nav > li:hover .subnav {
    display:block;
}

.nav > li .hide.subnav{
    display: none;
}
```

### **[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/a9AYE/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned

> Using jquery to change the CSS of the div above the link to hide the
>   subnav

So, guessing that, your `HTML` is something like this

```
<div class="subnav">Div Above the link One</div>
<a class="team" href="#">Link One</a>
<div class="subnav">Div Above the link Two</div>
<a class="team" href="#">Link Two</a>
```

So, you can use something like this

```
$('a.team').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Hide the div with class ".subnav" that is right above/brfore this link
    $(this).prev('.subnav').css('display','none'); 
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/JdjJh/)

P/S: You should have posted your `HTML` too.